# Azure Function App - skip trace logs to Application Insights

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, serilog

I’ve an isolated .NET 7 Azure Function App running in Azure. The Function App is connected to an Application Insights when created in Azure Portal.

Currently it uses Serilog to push all logs to Datadog. But it still ingest a lot of traces to Application Insights.

I prefer Datadog to analyze the application logs, but also think that Application Insights has some useful visualizations, e.g. function calls, failed calls etc.

Is it possible to keep using both Datadog and Application Insights, but stop ingesting the trace logs to Application Insights?

Comment: You'll need to create a custom telemetry processor that filters out the traces you don't want to be sent to Application Insights, then configure Application Insights to use the processor. In other words, you need to write some code, there is no one click way to do this.

Comment: @dhrm Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ziya Mert Karakas

But, I have used simple another workaround.

You can use **"logLevel"** in your **host.json** to send the logs in your traces table in application insights. If you do not use loglevel by default it is set to use **Information** level.

[image]

In My **host.json**, I have set it to "Warning" so I will get warning level and higher logs.

**`host.json`:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Warning"
      },
        "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "excludedTypes": "Request"
        },
        "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}
```

I have Created a simple timer trigger to send log to Datadog and application insights.

**`Function.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using System;

public static class Function1
{
    [Function("MyFunction")]
    public static void Run(
        [TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * * *")] FunctionContext context)
    {
        // Log using Serilog
        Log.Information("C# Timer trigger function executed at: {time}", DateTime.Now);
        Log.Information("Time in UTC: {time}", DateTime.UtcNow);
        Log.Information("This is Datadog LOG");
        


        // Log using the ILogger provided by Azure Functions
        var logger = context.GetLogger("Function1");
        logger.LogInformation("This is an Azure Functions log message.");
        logger.LogWarning("This is a Warning message");
        logger.LogError("this is a error message");

    }
}
```

**`program.cs`:**

```
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Serilog;
    using Serilog.Sinks.Datadog.Logs;
    using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
    using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
    
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Configure Serilog for Datadog
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.DatadogLogs(apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .CreateLogger();
        })
        .Build();
    
    host.Run();
```

**`Output`:**
**Without using : `loglevel`**

***other trace log are also available.***
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**With : `logLevel`**

***only logs which is equal or higher severityLevel of Warning are available.***

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

For Reference check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2).